# Smooth lower bound on a continuous function

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

Let $M$ be smooth manifold, and $f$ be a real valued non negative  continuous function on $M$. Must there exist  $g$ that is  real valued non negative  smooth function on $M$ such that $0\leq g \leq f$ and such that $g$ vanishes iff $f$ vanishes ?

Note : $M$ is Hausdorff and second countable.

Comment: If $M$ is T2 and second countable, then yes, definitely. Essentially because you can do that with indicators of relatively compact open sets and then go from there to approximate continuous functions.

Comment: @Gae.S. yes M is Hausdorff, second countable. I tried approximation ideas but can't seem to make sure that the approximating smooth function never exceeds my continuous function while also ensuring that it vanishes iff f vanishes

Comment: @Gae.S. If I understood your suggestion right, you cover $M$ by a family $\{B_i\}_i$ of precompact open sets then take a partition of unity $\{h_i\}$ subordinate to this open cover, finally set the approximating smooth function $g$ to be $\sum_i min(f[B_i]) h_i$. In case that's what you meant, then I don't see why $f$ vanishes iff $g$ vanishes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\{(\psi_\alpha, U_\alpha)\}_\alpha$ be a partition of unity on $M$.

Clearly, we have that $f\psi_\alpha$ is continuous on $M$ with support in $U_\alpha\subseteq M$. This effectively reduces the problem to finding a smooth approximation of a compactly supported function in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. if $\varphi_\alpha: V_\alpha\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow U_\alpha \subseteq M$ is a coordinate patch, then we are just finding a smooth approximation to the function $(f\psi_\alpha)\circ \varphi_\alpha: V_\alpha \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. This is a standard result in real analysis, so I will skip the detail. Hence, we can fine a $\tilde g_\alpha: V_\alpha \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{align}
0\le \tilde g_\alpha \le (f\psi_\alpha)\circ \varphi_\alpha.
\end{align}
In effect, we can define $g_\alpha:U_\alpha\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $g_\alpha = \tilde g_\alpha\circ \varphi_\alpha^{-1}$. Notice that $\operatorname{supp} g_\alpha \subset \operatorname{supp}(f\psi_\alpha)$ by construction. Finally, define
\begin{align}
0\le g = \sum_\alpha g_\alpha \le \sum_\alpha f\psi_\alpha = f.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where can I find a reference for the standard analysis result which you mention.

Comment: Will we have that $g$ vanishes iff $f$ vanishes ?

Comment: One direction is obvious since $g \le f$. For the other direction, you just need a $g$ to be non-zero when $f$ is non-zero. This again follows from classical construction on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: For the $\mathbb{R}^d$ result, this is usually done by convolving a bump function the given function. In general, there are a bunch of technical points when writing down the argument. But the points are purely technical, no real substances. However, if you haven't done this, you should do this as an exercise (at least for one time).

Comment: Just to convince yourself that this can be done, you should work in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$. Draw a picture.

Comment: Does convoluting a bump function with a continuous function yield a smooth function?

Comment: Try taking the derivative of a convolution. What do you notice?

Comment: Ok I took the derivative and saw what you mean. Now I know I m missing lots of technicalities regarding using convolutions for approximations . Thanks  for your answer.

Comment: Can I please have a reference of how the result is obtained by convolution of bump functions as you mention in one of the previous comments ?